# Alarm notification with Capacitor JS

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I need to make an alarm clock function so that the notification hangs permanently on the screen when the phone is not turned on and also vibrates. Until the user presses the stop button. How to do it? I can't find normal references or examples. I can make a native module and pass it through Kotlin, but is there a way to do it all through the capacitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anyone has yet implemented this feature in Capacitor, but if you write native code, you can [create a Capacitor plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/creating-plugins) to use that code easily with Capacitor.

[create-capacitor-plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/create-capacitor-plugin) can help you get started.